# Retrieve mysql data and output as script.

Tags: php, mysql

I got this mysql table with a text field. One of the text entries contains:

```
<?
if(isset($_GET["id"])) {
include($index.".php");
} else {
include("front.php");
}
?>
```

How do I output that mysql data as the script is intented to do, when i retrieve mysql data? It just outputs the php in my index file without it doing anything.

Comment: Danger alert - executable code stored in DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eval()`.

See here: [PHP Manual - eval()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.eval.php)

But you should consider finding another solution to your problem that made you put the code into a mysql table. Most of the time things like that are easy avoidable and considered bad practice.

Comment: Well, what is the problem with storing a code like this? I can't see any way this being insecure, it's only a include script for pages, I won't store secure data. The code is also validated before inserted.

Comment: Well, I didn`t say that it's insecure, I said it is bad practice. If it's only a include script for pages, why not put it into a .php file and include it?

Comment: I'll figure something else out.

Comment: Sorry for explaining myself wrong, I'm at bit tired these days because of the flu hanging around. Anyway, enough with the crying :) I've made a page where I can move my content around using jQuery sortable function. From top to bottom: Slideshow, "Content", Two boxes for misc. stuff. Now I want to be able to edit and add these boxes to my page online. Like a little content management system. The "Content" is where my pages from ?id= gets included.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get why there has to be PHP code in the db. You could just give everything a ID and store ID, type, position, content etc. in the db.

Comment: It already has a id and a listing id. And i also figured out the jQuery script so i can move things around and it will save to mysql on-the-fly. But the mysql storage would be for the individual contents? Tell me then, what to do if I want to create some new content on the CMS system. Where to store the php codes if not in the database?

Comment: To explain myself more detailed. I got one row in the sql table called slideshow. This contains the slideshow html code to insert into the box on my site. Then I got another one called extra. This is two boxes sidebyside for url to misc content. Then i got content. Which contains this php code to provide information to the site for which place to place the content i include (Main content)

Comment: Let's just leave it here. I'll do something else. Thanks anything. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

First all, the code posted above isn't the way to go. This is an example of how not to code in general.

**Why**

1) You should avoid short PHP tags like, `<?`, `<?=` in order to make your code more portable. Because if server has an option like, `allow_short_tags` disabled, then the web server would simply treat your code as a plain text. (not as PHP script)

2) An error in `if isset($_GET...)` block, because you're telling the script to `include($index.'.php')` when `$_GET['id']` has any value.Any! You do not even filter the `$_GET['id']`

And according  to your last comments, this is an answer to "why you should not store PHP code in a database".

In order to read the code from database you should (in general)

- Connect to SQL server
- Run the query
- Fetch the result
- Evaluate the response via `eval()` function

But what if your SQL server is busy and does not respond? The script must be halted then.
This is generally considered as a `bad practice` and you should never code this way.

Why to do all those aforementioned "operations", when you can simply do:

`<?php
include('some_codes.php');// or better require()`

**Another important thing**

When you rely on `$_GET['some_key']` and going to include some file according to the value of the `$_GET` key, you should always validate the `$_GET['some_key']`. A very basic validation would look like this:

```
<?php

if ( isset($_GET['foo']) ){

   if ( file_exists('../path' . $_GET['foo']) ){
      // seems like a valid one
      // do include then
   }
}
```

**Conclusion**
1) Do not use short tags, use a full one instead - `<?php`
2) Do not trust user inputs, i.e never trust values you got from `$_GET` and `$_POST`.
3) Keep the code in the files and then do include when needed.

Comment: This was very good information. Though the <? was a fault. I'm always using <?php. Though i like to have a paging system on my site where i include the specific file from ?id= so i change contents inside a div. I'm currently trying to build a little CMS system. So I can't make a new page and simply do include or require each time. Kind of takes the idea away from a CMS system

Comment: In general, you should create each class for each page, like `class Edit_Article, class Create_Article` and then you should implement an Autoloader via `spl_autoload_register`